# Should I avoid duplicate entries in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

From a design perspective, I'm wondering if basically a table that has 2 fields (id, name) should ever have a duplicate for name.  I'm designing a database that has a table called projects(pro_id,pro_name) and a table called categories(cat_id,cat_name). Project names will certainly be unique.  A given project may have a number of categories associated with it and there will be a third table called procat(procat_id,pro_id,cat_id) to do this.  The thing is, there could be several projects that have categories with the same name. So projects 1 and 7 might both have a category called "Bathroom". My question is should my categories table reflect just 1 entry for "Bathroom" or 2 separate entries with 2 ids?  Note that these categories and what they do in the database will be different from each other.  Project 1's bathroom may have one set of data associated with it (color=blue, size=400, etc) while Proect 7's bathroom may have different data associated with it (all recorded in different tables).

Thanks for any help! Currently I'm leaning towards duplicate entries in the categories table, but i want to make sure I'm not missing something that will cause problems later on.

Comment: Will you ever want to display all projects in a category? If so you should avoid having dupes, this makes it easier to query later, and also gives you "normalised" data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: In English, do we have a separate copy of the word bathroom for every individual bathroom? No, we combine words: project 1's bathroom is blue. You can do the same in a database, e.g. (pro_id PK, cat_id PK, color). In fact, associating a predicate sentence with each table is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether values are duplicated in a column is determined by what the rows in the table mean and what possible table values can arise according to the business rules. Eg: Suppose you decide that every thing of some sort has its own unique id among things of that sort. Then ids will be unique in a table that has a row for each things with a given properties. But suppose rows in a table contain id & colour values that make "thing ID comes in colour COLOUR" into a true statement. Then if things come in only one colour then colour will be unique but if things can come in multiple colours then column colour will not be unique. Although id-colour pairs will be unique.

You as DBA must decide on such a meaning or *predicate* for each table that determines that table's rows in a given situation. Ie a statement template parameterized by columns, where the table holds rows that make the template into a true statement.

Your collection of tables must have sufficient predicates to be able to describe any situation that arises, while you don't want rows in a table or tables to be stating the same thing. Determine good designs by learning & applying an information modeling method & normalization.

> The thing is, there could be several projects that have categories with the same name.

Make sure you clearly separate two distinct notions and don't call both of thm "category": a thing that exists separately in its own project (which is how you used "category" in the quote) vs a thing that is a *kind* of one of those, with its own property like a name, with multiple projects possibly being associated the same kind, but with other properties on a project-kind basis. It seems that you picked the word "category" as *a synonym for kind* (as is *department*) so maybe this is what you really mean. Ie there is a kind/category *of room* named "bathroom" and different projects have *the same kind/category of room* but different project-kind/category pairs, ie *rooms* out there in the world, have different sets of properties & different values for the same property.

> My question is should my categories table reflect just 1 entry for "Bathroom" or 2 separate entries with 2 ids?

Suppose you have unique category & project ids. Consider table `c(id, name)` with predicate "category ID is called by name NAME". If a category is a thing associated with only has one name, `id` will be unique. Otherwise a thing can be associated with multiple names so `id`-`name` subrows will be unique. You have said that different categories can have the same name. On the other hand from what you have said a table for pc(pid, cid, name) "in project PID category CID is called by name CNAME" then since projects don't share categories `CID` is unique, although PID is not. Note that in this case `c`'s predicate "category ID is called by name NAME" also means "for some project PID, in project PID category CID is called by name NAME". So `c` is just `select cid as id from pc`. So you don't need `c` if you have `pc`.

On the other hand if you decided that category ids are not unique but instead categories are uniquely identified by a project-category id pair then in `c` `name` will not be unique and in `cp` `PID`-`CID` pairs will be unique but `CID` & `PID` won't be.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are getting at. I should have 2 tables: projects(p_id,p_name) and categories(c_id, p_id, c_name). I don't necessarily care to store various names in my database (as one might store all the words in the english language). My category name is just acting as a friendly identifier for the end user. In my rules, there can be several "bathroom" names, but they are all different if they are in different projects. I would then just add a UNIQUE constraint on all 3 fields in the categories table, right? to ensure users don't create 2 cats with same name in 1 project.

Comment: @Joe in your proposed table, to ensure names are unique per project you would create a unique constraint on (p_id, c_name). If you include c_id (assuming it's a key) it won't work.

Comment: @philipxy If things come in only one colour then *id* will be unique but if things can come in multiple colours then column *id* will not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I currently see two possibilities:

Possibility one: Include details immediately in the Categories data set. This makes it reasonable to keep all of the repeated names because they are discriminated here.

Possibility two: Do not include any details besides the name in Categories, as you currently have it and combine them. If this ID is just acting as a name and you have other factors to sort by (discerning one bathroom project from another by project id for instance) then you should combine them. If you don't, you could run into scaling issues since you are using up so much unnecessary space.

Answer (score 0):

Your Categories table needs only one entry for each Category

Any differences between "Bathrooms" in the Categories table should actually be stored in the Projects table, because they are specific to a Project and not specific to a Category.  All that should be stored about a "Bathroom" in the Categories table is the information that all Bathrooms will have in common.

In a relational database, the objective is to find like entities and group them into tables.  For example, "Projects" and "Categories" are different entities and you have correctly placed them into separate tables.  The rows of these tables then represent different types of these entities("Bedroom", "Closet") etc., and because changing the color or size of a "Bathroom" does not change its "Category", that information should be stored elsewhere.  In your case, this is likely the Projects table.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to question but i hope this might help you somehow:

remember that :

you do not need to check for duplicate for pro_name but yes,if your ID field is duplicate (sometime it happens if you manually try to insert)and identity is not set to column. So, always assign one table IDs to Identity column to make every field unique auto-number and remove duplicate insert .

answer to your question:

Q. My question is should my categories table reflect just 1 entry for "Bathroom"      or 2 separate entries with 2 ids?

ANS: Nope, because you might later have similar or same name (like: "bathroom") ,since both table id are set to auto identity and not duplicate you are just fine.

example:

```
pro_id=1, pro_name="bathroom"
pro_id=2, pro_name="bathroom"
pro_id=3, pro_name="bathroom"
pro_id=4, pro_name="bathroom"
```

but it will be duplicate if your table is like this,and nobody wants this:

```
pro_id=1, pro_name="bathroom"
pro_id=1, pro_name="bathroom"
pro_id=2, pro_name="bathroom"
pro_id=2, pro_name="bathroom"
```

note: 
what I do here is on projects(pro_id,pro_name) and categories(cat_id,cat_name)
I create pro_id on categories and link foreign key this is because you said
"A given project may have a number of categories associated with it".
after this you might even do not need third table.